# What to consider while build a web app as big, traffic intestive, successful as Facebook?

Tags: php, mysql, facebook, database-design

I have an idea that require me to build a web application which could be as successful as Facebook. I know the foundation for such an idea is very important and i would love to have to some as to what to consider while building - with a team - it.

Any suggestions from database consideration to coding will be highly welcome.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Shouldn't your team of hopefully highly trained experts be able to tell you that? If not, consider hire consultants that can. Alternative: stop worrying about premature optimizations and just get started. It's what Zuckerberg did too.

Comment: Care to share you idea with us - the team :D

Comment: This most probably belongs to [programmers.stackexchange.com](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I can't help but i think this is belongs to http://clientsfromhell.net/

Comment: Thank you very much everyone. @Gordon: My team is not highly skilled and we intend to start small. We just want to lay a good foundation for growth. I'll check out the other links.

Comment: @Gordon, Right on! ++++1

Answer (score 3):

Just build it, and be prepared to redesign it later. It won't get as big as Facebook if you get hung up on trying to write something infinitely scalable from day 1.

Facebook got popular by *launching*. Their v1.0 certainly wouldn't have scaled to 500 million users, and if they'd tried to make it do that, it would have been delayed for months, and still wouldn't have scaled well enough (because they wouldn't have known where the bottlenecks were until they actually had a huge userbase)

Comment: I always tend to plan alot. This is kind of motivating.

Comment: Stop planning, ship. Google does it by delivering early as beta... you'll never know what works and what doesn't in the lab.

Answer (score 2):

It all depends on your application. But below are some things you should consider, and ask yourself before starting up a large project.

I don't agree that you should "just built it". You need to consider the way you project initial should be heading, and do some well thought planning. Then you can always change your mind later. I'm not suggesting a water-fall model though, you should do it in an agile sort of way, so you don't spent to much time on eighter building or planning before reevaluating.

- How much data is required in your database, and how large?
- How is this data stored?
- How many concurrent users do you expect?
- Is your application read- or write heavy?
- Do you plan on making your application distributed? (Do you have the resources to do so?)